# Elastic Search mapping on Java Spring startup

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring data elastic search and i'm having a document that i want to store. I'm wondering, is there a way on the microservice starts to automatically send to elastic search the mapping for this document? I have the repository defined and currently when i start the service, there is no mapping added to the elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entity should have `@Document` annotation on class level,
and for activating index auto-creation during bootstrapping
there is argument `createIndex` for this annotation.
When this argument is set to `true` - an index will be automatically created.

For improving index settings during creation, there is a separate annotation `@Setting`

More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.repositories.autocreation)

Actual index mapping is created based on entity’s field annotations (like `@Field`, `@Id` etc).

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations) is more info about available entity annotations

Comment: Yes, the index will be created, but what about the mapping?

Comment: Mappings will be created based on entity annotations, I've updated my answer with additional info